# React Native 'popover' component with navigation

Tags: react-native

Anyone knows of a `popover` component for `RN` with `React Navigation` built in? similar to https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/views/popovers/

I have tried https://github.com/steffeydev/react-native-popover-view#readme but it doesn't have the `navigation` (able to have screens stack within the popover) - same author have a [component](http://react-navigation-popover) but was outdated and won't work with `React Navigation v5.x`

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution? Also looking for this, and am a bit surprised it doesn't come out of the box, or at least in RN or RNN libraries.

Comment: No I haven't. I ended up hacking it by creating Views on top of each other then trigger visibility. Not a nice solution but it will do for now